# titlesec: \paragraph don't displays with explicit option

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I need to use the `explicit` option of `titlesec` package. However, the `paragraph` is not displays with follow code:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
```

Maybe I dont' know the `explicit` option meaning well, but if to try it with argument, you will get an error:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries #1}{}{}{}[]
```

[image]

The MWE is...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toctitles,pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}

 \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries #1}{}{}{}[]
%\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]

\begin{document}

\paragraph{test} aa

\paragraph{test} bb

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace in you preamble: `\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries #1}{}{}{}[]` with `\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{}{#1}`.

The explicit argument can be used in the last mandatory argument only. The first argument is for describing the common formatting of `label+title`, not title alone. Also you can delete the optional argment if it's empty…

[image]